# Django stop serialiser save in CreateAPIView overriding pre_save

Tags: django-views, django-rest-framework

I have some validations to perform based on the serializer data before the serializer data is saved and stop the save in case the validations fail. I am using the pre_save which executes before the perform_create method and I am able to do the validations but I do not understand how to stop the serializer.save() in case these validations fail.

I can give any other details required upon request. And I would like to stick to using CreateApiView unless it is totally unavoidable.

Comment: Which version of DRF are you using? DRF 3.x no longer uses the `pre_save()` function http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call `serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)` which will raise an exception and stop the code from executing any further if there is an error in the serializer

If you are using the `pre_save()` function you could always raise a parse error exception, triggered when a condition is met:

```
from rest_framework import exceptions
raise exceptions.ParseError({"error":["Something went wrong"]})
```